# XSLT not working to attach stylesheet to XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

```
Element root = document.createElement("urlset");
    document.setXmlStandalone(true);
    document.appendChild(root);
    root.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
    root.setAttribute("xmlns:xhtml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
    
    org.w3c.dom.ProcessingInstruction pi = document.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"C:\\\\CanonWebApp\\\\utility\\\\sitemap.xslt encoding=\\\"utf-8\"");

      document.insertBefore((Node) pi, root);
      document.setXmlStandalone(true);
```

[image: xml image]

I am adding stylesheet using processing instruction to my xml. I have kept stylesheet in my local but still, I am getting error as below screenshot:

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

Comment: The syntax is `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet-uri"?>`. So for a `file` URI it would be e.g. `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:/CanonWebApp/utility/sitemap.xsl"?>`. These days, however, most browsers (Google Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Chromium based Edge) do not support `file` URIs to `xml-stylesheet`s.

Comment: Thanks for reply org.w3c.dom.ProcessingInstruction pi = document.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"C:\\\\CanonWebApp\\\\utility\\\\sitemap.xslt encoding=\\\"utf-8\"");  but this needs 2 argument as string and the one that you have mentioned will not go with document.createProcessingInstruction is there any other way I can do

Comment: The Java syntax to create the XML I have posted with the DOM API would be `document.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"file:///C:/CanonWebApp/utility/sitemap.xsl\"")`. But which application do you expect to read that PI, which does state "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it"?

Comment: Additionally, `encoding` is not one of the known pseudo attributes to be put in the `xml-stylesheet` pi, it would be `charset`. But you need to delimit the value of the `href` pseudo attribute correctly e.g. `document.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"file:///C:/CanonWebApp/utility/sitemap.xsl\" charset=\"UTF-8\"")`

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanku for reply , but I have tried with above syntax it is  not working .I am using google chrome and internet explorer but no luck

Comment: Which error message or warning do you get with Internet Explorer? As for Chrome, it doesn't load file based XSLT from an `xml-stylesheet` pi, unless you start it with special command line access to explicitly allow local file access.

Comment: Where is that XSLT file exactly, on the same local file system as the XML document? Or is `\\\\CanonWebApp` an attempt to load from a network server?

Comment: Also, is there only a problem when you create the XML with Java, as you have shown? Does a hand-created/edited XML with your PI load the XSLT in IE or even Chrome?

Comment: Hi  @MartinHonnen  As I am making a sitemap , so In internet explorer  after applying stylesheet , url should appear as clickable link, but it is showing as static url  which is not clickable.. .that means xsl stylesheet is not getting applied to it.

Comment: Yes XSLT file is in same local file system as the xml document , only  in different folder.

Comment: In view source code i see the correct tags forming for xml page  in internet explorerfor sitemap , but  in front end it is showing a static url. Whereas in chrome it is coming as blank and cant even view source code

Comment: So how does a minimal XML document and a minimal XSLT look? Does that XSLT work normally with the XML format you have and only fails if you try to generate the XML and the PI with Java? It is still not clear whether the problem is on the Java side, on the XML, on the XSLT or simply a browser problem.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen,Thanks for your reply, As I was into something else so could not reply for this post. It will not work on local machine as it is working when I deployed on server.